# Bancos de dados para Clientes diferentes

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4

Estou aprendendo MVC 4 e gostaria de saber se existe um jeito de com apenas 1 modelo acessar bancos de dados diferentes?
Por exemplo, eu tenho um sistema online e para cada cliente eu tenho um banco separado.
Qual seria a melhor prática para fazer isso?

Comment: Deixa eu ver se eu entendi, é 1 sistema (site) e que vários clientes vão acessar a mesma URL mas baseado no cliente tem que mudar o banco.

Comment: Teria algum motivo plausível para isso? Não entendi sua necessidade...

Comment: Caro Rvenerosomorici, vi como tag Entity Framework ORM, e ai a sua questão não diz nada, poderia melhorar sua questão?

Comment: PauloHDSousa, seria isso mesmo.
Ronny Amarante, é para aprendizado.

Comment: Harry Potter, O MVC4 trabalha com o Entity Framework, e a minha questão é justamente essa se com 1 modelo no projeto eu consigo trabalhar com diversos bancos.

Answer (score 4):

Dois cenários:

### 1. Um sistema, acessando vários bancos de dados

Defina um contexto para cada banco de dados:

```
public class Cliente1Context : DbContext
{
    public Cliente1Context() : base("ConnectionStringDoCliente1") {}

    // Definição dos DbSets
    ...
}

public class Cliente2Context : DbContext
{
    public Cliente2Context() : base("ConnectionStringDoCliente2") {}

    // Definição dos DbSets
    ...
}
```

#### Web.config para este caso

```
<configuration>
  ...
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="ConnectionStringDoCliente1" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" connectionString="Dados da conexão do cliente 1" />
    <add name="ConnectionStringDoCliente2" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" connectionString="Dados da conexão do cliente 2" />
  </connectionStrings>
  ...
</configuration>
```

### 2. Uma instância do sistema para cada cliente

Neste caso, deve ser um contexto só com uma configuração só:

```
public class SistemaContext : DbContext
{
    public SistemaContext() : base("DefaultConnection") {}

    // Definição dos DbSets
    ...
}
```

No seu `Web.config`, defina apenas uma *Connection String*:

```
<configuration>
  ...
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="DefaultConnection" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" connectionString="Dados da Default Connection" />
  </connectionStrings>
  ...
</configuration>
```

Defina uma configuração para cada cliente. Isso se faz acessando o menu do *Configuration Manager*:

[image: Acesso ao Configuration Manager]

Defina uma nova configuração:

[image: Nova configuração]

Digite o nome do seu cliente, por exemplo:

[image: Definindo nova configuração para cliente]

Clique com o botão direito no seu arquivo `Web.config` e escolha a opção `Add Config Transform`:

[image: Add Config Transform]

Repare que irá aparecer uma variação do seu arquivo `Web.config`. Isso é o que chamamos de **arquivo de transformação**:

[image: Web.config]

Abra o novo arquivo de transformação. Repare que dentro dele tem uns exemplos comentados. Basta alterar o exemplo que tem a *Connection String* para a *Connection String* do seu cliente:

```
<configuration xmlns:xdt="http://schemas.microsoft.com/XML-Document-Transform">
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="DefaultConnection" 
      connectionString="Connection String do Cliente 1" 
      xdt:Transform="SetAttributes" xdt:Locator="Match(name)"/>
  </connectionStrings>
  ...
</configuration>
```

Basta agora fazer um *Build* ou um *Publish* utilizando a nova configuração criada. No caso, "Cliente1".

Mais exemplos? http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=125889

Comment: Muito obrigado Cigano, hoje testarei, amanhã eu posto se funcionou.

Answer (score 0):

Uma solução para o seu problema é atribuir a cada cliente uma `connection string` diferente que aponte para a BD que lhe pertence.

Quando o utilizador entrar, pode consultar a `connection string` do utilizador e para as seguintes operações usa-la para ligar à BD correcta.

Isto implica no entanto que tenha uma BD central onde guarde a informação que relaciona utilizador/BD.

Nota:
Sugeria que editasse a sua resposta e nos explicasse melhor o sistema que tem e qual o propósito para tornar a pergunta mais clara e as respostas poderem ser mais úteis.

Comment: Omni, é apenas aprendizado, eu não tenho um sistema específico, só quero aprender como fazer com apenas 1 modelo no projeto trabalhar com bancos variáveis de acordo com o cliente

Comment: Nesse caso então diria que a forma que descrevi pode ajudá-lo. No entanto a resposta assume que todos as BDs partilham a mesma estrutura.

Answer (score -1):

Olá, não conheço esse tal MVC 4, mas com a experiência que tenho em BD, criaria uma tabela para salvar os dados de todos os clientes, ou entao separaria por pessoa, e classificaria essa pessoa de diversas formas, como cliente, fornecedor, usuario, tecnico, administrador, etc, conforme a necessidade, também se pode cadastrar enderecos de seus clientes e classifica-los como cobranca, residencial, correspondencia, etc, basta linkar usando uma chave estrangeira como id_cliente por exemplo e assim vai...

Answer (score -1):

Tudo é questão da logica de negocio,

Sugiro que faça tabelas, com relacionamentos e tudo que se tem direito.

Pois tua infraestrutura não precisaria ser tão grande, como se caso precisasse de bases de dados distintas.