# Deploy automatizado - Manutenção de versões para vários clientes

Tags: sql, sql-server, asp.net-mvc-5, entity-framework-6

Qual é a melhor forma de automatizar o deploy ?

Tendo 1 deploy para cada cliente, qual é a forma mais fácil de manter todos esses deploys ? migrations de banco de dados e todo tratamento de versão?

Em um exemplo que se tem 100 clientes

Comment: Eu não abriria uma instância por usuário, apenas para testes. Faria uma instância só e ele pode logar nela.

Comment: @CiganoMorrisonMendez, A dúvida é relacionada a deploy automatizado, e fácil manutenção de 100+ deploy do mesmo aplicativo...

Comment: Pra este caso, a multitenência ia ser uma mão na roda. Apenas um deploy com criação do ambiente por usuário.

Comment: @CiganoMorrisonMendez pensei que você não era a favor do multi tenant...

Comment: Depende da situação. Pro caso de individualização do ambiente por usuário, sou a favor.

Comment: @CiganoMorrisonMendez e por empresa? em aplicações corporativas?

Comment: Aí eu acho melhor não fazer multitenente.

Comment: @CiganoMorrisonMendez ah, agora fez sentido...é isso que quero saber...como manter versão para esse tipo de aplicação...para empresas...

Comment: Decida-se. Ou é tenência pra usuário ou pra empresa. Não existe caso que resolva pra tudo.

Comment: @CiganoMorrisonMendez sem multi tenant, apenas single por empresa

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Um bom começo está [na alternativa 2 desta resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/17095/bancos-de-dados-para-clientes-diferentes/17135#17135), em que explico como fazer para criar transformações para o arquivo `web.config`. [Aqui tem mais um exemplo](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/80698/connectionstring-diferente-para-builds-diferentes/80700#80700).

Para o seu caso, teria que haver uma transformação por cliente. A vantagem disso é que não apenas a *connection string* pode ser modificada, mas toda e qualquer configuração do cliente.

O procedimento é totalmente amigável ao Azure, visto que você pode escolher qual configuração usar na hora do Web Deploy.